# How to implement a simple github markdown badge to show monthly download

Tags: github, markdown, badge

As titled, I would like to have a badge for, let's say, this [repo](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/kotlin-unsigned)

Looking [online](https://shields.io/), I found, for example, this:

`[![npm](https://img.shields.io/npm/dm/localeval.svg)]()`
[image: npm]

I tried to embed in all the possible ways
`[![npm](https://img.shields.io/npm/dm/kotlin-graphics/kotlin-unsigned.svg)]()` [image: npm]

but I always get invalid or 0 (which cannot be because I saw the github statistics)

What am I missing?

Comment: Do your Github statistics provide a *monthly* download counter? I wouldn't think so and I believe therefore it is not possible to display this via shields.io

Comment: This answers my question, even if negatively... ok thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The npm in your URL stands for Node package manager which is not what you want.
Use the URL for Github instead:

Total downloads: [image: Github Downloads (total)]

`[![Github Downloads (total)](https://img.shields.io/github/downloads/kotlin-graphics/kotlin-unsigned/total.svg)]()`

Unfortunately it does not seem to be possible to get a badge for the monthly downloads like this. But maybe you want to show the download count for the latest release:

[image: Github Downloads (monthly)]

`[![Github Downloads (monthly)](https://img.shields.io/github/downloads/kotlin-graphics/kotlin-unsigned/latest/total.svg)]()`